# A2 Terminator Fan Replacement

Tags: scrypt

I am after a couple of fans for my A2 as the bearings have gone.

From what i can see and have measured, they are a uncommon size at 105/106mm. Is this correct?

Any suggestions on replacements?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have a full size a2 and it is a normal 120mm fan but you need to get one with high flow fans. I'm currently trying to find the best fans to keep me under 50 c but no be as loud as the original fans

Comment: Have you had any joy finding any high flow low noise fans?